# Setting the path to viminfo in windows

Tags: vim

I am trying to set the path to my **viminfo** file in WIN 7 using an env variable.

Something like:

```
:set viminfo+=n$HOME\\vimfiles\\_viminfo
```

I've tried all the obvious permutations, backslash, fwd slash etc. I either get an invalid character or an invalid number.  I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why the two backslashes?

Comment: I don't get an error message. What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: two backslashes are just one of the many unsucessful permutations I've tried, based on suggestions I've found online.

I get  Error detected while processing c:\Users

Comment: well <blush> turns out the error was from another line in the vimrc file that had accidently gotten messed up.  The command I posted seems to work perfectly.  A _viminfo file showed up in ~\vimfiles